# how to get all records after the minimum in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, search

How do I get all records (after the minimum value)

ex: the minimum value is 7, I want to get all records after it.

```
Date             Value    
2020-03-11       20 
2020-02-25       10
2020-02-20       7.5      
2020-02-15       7        
2020-01-10       10       
2019-12-07       15
```

I tried

```
min1=dfs[i].loc[dfs[i]['Value'] == dfs[i]['Value'].min()]['Date'].values[0]
dfs[i][min1:]
```

but this raised an error
'TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [2020-02-12T00:00:00.000000000] of '

Note: I have a list of data frames.

Comment: `df.loc[[df['value'].idxmin()]:, ]` This should give you all the values after the minimum

Comment: Cannot edit the previous comment so posting the answer again after correcting the extra bracket there `df.loc[df['value'].idxmin():, ]`

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the rows after the first minimum by doing this

`df.loc[df['Value'].idxmin():, ]`

EDIT: Based on the comment below to get rows after the minimum, not including the minimum `df.loc[df['Value'].idxmin()+1:, ]`

Please note I am assuming the index is continuous integer, if not please reset the index. If your index is not integer and non monotonic then please check @Valdi_Bo answer below

Comment: This expression retrieves rows **starting from** the "minimal" row, whereas the OP wants rows **after** this row.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the DataFrame contains:

```
          Date  Value
A1  2020-03-11   20.0
H2  2020-02-25   10.0
E3  2020-02-20    7.5
C4  2020-02-15    7.0
B5  2020-01-10   10.0
M6  2019-12-07   15.0
```

To proove that my method works in all possible cases, I deliberately
chose non-numeric and non-monotonic index, but the index must be unique.

Note that:

1. `idxm = df.Value.idxmin()` gets the index of row with minimal
   *Value* - `C4`.
2. `df.loc[:idxm].index` retrieves the "initial" part of the index,
   up to the "minimal" row (including) -
   `Index(['A1', 'H2', 'E3', 'C4'], dtype='object')`.
3. `df.index.difference(df.loc[:idxm].index)` retrieves the other part
   of the index - `Index(['B5', 'M6'], dtype='object')`.

So this leads to the conclusion that the right expression is:

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(df.loc[:idxm].index)]
```

The result of this expression is:

```
          Date  Value
B5  2020-01-10   10.0
M6  2019-12-07   15.0
```

Other possible solution:

```
df.loc[df.Value.shift().idxmin():]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me to get the solution. I did a small change ` df.loc[df.index.difference(df.loc[idxm:].index)] ` so I get A1, H2 and E3.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `shift` to get the shifted series, then compare that with `min`:

```
df[df.Value.shift()==df.Value.min()]
```

Output:

```
         Date  Value
4  2020-01-10   10.0
```

If you just want to get `Value`:

```
df.loc[df.Value.shift()==df.Value.min(), 'Value']
```

Output:

```
4    10.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```